# Getting the element by class name

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am trying to get the AQI(us) number in the ring as shown on this website https://air-quality.com/place/philippines/metro-manila/bb4d16ee?lang=en&standard=aqi_us. After running the code i get this error

> Error: Run-time error '91' Object variable or with block variable not
>   set

```
Sub Webscraping()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate ("https://air-quality.com/place/philippines/metro-manila/bb4d16ee?lang=en&standard=aqi_us")

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: Loop

Set ht = ie.document

Set allRowOfData = ht.getElementsByClassName("indexValue")(0)

Dim myValue10 As String: myValue10 = allRowOfData.innerText
Range("D13").Value = myValue10

End Sub()
```

Comment: Your code seems to work OK here, with no errors, and it wrote a `23` into `D13` which was the number in the ring.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yea it seems fine now, thank you